# Системный разделить целой и дробной части js?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли возможнось узнать системный разделить целой и дробной части, который установлен у пользователя с помощью js? Т.е. Интересует не язык браузера, а именно то, что юзер в винде себе кастомно настроил.

**update**
Если в броузере настрен русский язык, то метод

```
'1.1'.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2)
```

вернет ','. Для английского (сша) - это будет '.'

[image: языковые настройки Chrom]

Меня же интересует разделитель, который юзер выбрал для себя глобально, для системы.

[image: системные настройки языка]

и этот разделитель используется, например, в Excel.
Так вот задача (точнее пожелание) заказчика, что бы в аппке (React.js) выводился такой же разделитель, как и в эксельке.

Comment: Что такое системный разделитель? Можете приложить описание этого словосочетания

Comment: в яваскрипте разделитель только точка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможно вам нужен [intl.numberformat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)?

Comment: добавил развернутое пояснение задачи для не фронтов